# Android mutate() changes appearance of LayerDrawable

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LayerDrawable defined in xml that I load from disk and reuse in a few parts of my application. To prevent an instance of my LayerDrawable from affecting other instances I call mutate like defined [here](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/05/02/drawable-mutations/). However calling mutate is also changing the appearance of the drawing.  I can duplicate on tablets, phones, and the simulator.  Anyone have experience with this?